# `:=` used for multiple simultaneous assign in data table does not respect updated values

Tags: r, data.table

`:=` used for multiple simultaneous assign in data table does not respect updated values. The column x is incremented, and then I intend to assign updated value of x to y. Why is the value not equal to intended ?

```
> z = data.table(x = 1:5, y= 1:5)
> z[, `:=` (x = x + 1, y = x)]
> # Actual
> z
   x y
1: 2 1
2: 3 2
3: 4 3
4: 5 4
5: 6 5
> # Expected
> z
   x y
1: 2 2
2: 3 3
3: 4 4
4: 5 5
5: 6 6
```

Comment: This seems to work. Michael, can you explain the operators, or can you point to a link

Comment: {x <- x + 1; .(x, x)} : Are we passing simply two lists ? Why is there a need of x <- (x + 1) ? What does .(x, x) imply here ? Sorry, if that is a very basic thing ? What does the separator `;` imply ?

Comment: I have expanded a bit in my answer & deleted my original comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two more alternatives for you to consider. As noted, `data.table` doesn't do the dynamic scoping in the way that `dplyr::mutate` does, so `y = x` still refers to `z$x` in the second part of your statement. You can consider [Filing an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) if you strongly prefer this way.

1. explicitly assign the new `x` inline:

```
z[, `:=` (x = (x <- x + 1), y = x)]
```

In the environment where `j` is evaluated, now an object `x` is created to overwrite `z$x` temporarily. This should be very similar to what `dplyr` is doing internally -- evaluating the arguments of `mutate` sequentially and updating the column values iteratively.

2. Switch to `LHS := RHS` form (see `?set`):

```
z[ , c('x', 'y') := {
  x = x + 1
  .(x, x)
}]
```

`.` is shorthand in `data.table` for `list`. In `LHS := RHS` form, `RHS` must evaluate to a `list`; each element of that `list` will be one column in the assignment.

More compactly:

```
z[ , c('x', 'y') := {x = x + 1; .(x, x)}]
```

`;` allows you to write multiple statements on the same line (e.g. `3+4; 4+5` will run `3+4` then `4+5`). `{` creates a way to wrap multiple statements and return the final value, see `?"{"`. Implicitly you're using this whenever you write `if (x) { do_true } else { do_false }` or `function(x) { function_body }`.

Comment: Superb explanation !

Comment: I don't think filling an issue will help. That would break some users code in a badly way. Moreover it is counterintuitive, having in mind that we are constructing a list expression on the RHS, and not a list of expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `x` is not updated while doing the calculation for `y`. You might use the same assignment as `x` for `y`

```
library(data.table)
z[, `:=` (x = x + 1, y = x + 1)]
```

Or update it separately.

```
z[, x := x + 1][, y:= x]
```

---

This behavior is different as compared to `mutate` from `dplyr` where the following works.

```
library(dplyr)
z %>%  mutate(x = x + 1, y = x)
```

Comment: `z[condition, x := x + 1][condition, y:= x]` will require condition, if any, to do these assignments multiple times. I wish to avoid this as in `mutate`